# The laptop with a hard drive locked

Tags: hard-drive, passwords, smart

I have a laptop in the workplace with a hard drive which has been locked by the previous employee. Nobody knows the current password and I'm trying to figure out how to overcome this problem. It has AMI BIOS inside, I already tried to reset CMOS, tried to bruteforce the password by using Universal Boot Disk CD and Hiren Boot CD. Nothing helped.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how can we either get access to this harddrive or to remove this hard drive and insert a new one?

Comment: It depends on what type of protection is actually in use. Can you access the drive if you connect it to another computer?

Comment: Is that previous employee dead or unreachable? Sounds like an illegal action (if done in the workplace). Threaten with prosecution if he does not give you the PW.

Comment: "how can we […] remove this hard drive and insert a new one?" – What's the problem with this? Did the employee physically locked or booby-trapped the computer case?

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment by @kamil-maciorowski:

> You can see "Hard Disk is still locked" on the first picture. [This] password locks [the] HDD, not [the] BIOS. It's called [an] ATA password [and] it is stored in the disk itself. The disk electronics/firmware denies access unless you give the right password (via BIOS prompt in this case). Therefore [...] the disk will stay locked even if connected to another computer or dock.

This disk lock is a built-in security feature of the disk. It is part of the ATA specification, and thus not specific to any brand or device.

[It is apparently possible (at least in some instances) to remove a password with Linux and hdparm](https://serverfault.com/questions/712849/how-to-unlock-a-ssd-disk-with-hdparm) or to at least do an disk erasure with a master password.

The other option is to replace the hard disk directly. As noted, since the security feature is on the disk (in the controller), this could be a viable option if you merely wish to retain the laptop.